# Is multiplication in a normed algebra distributive?

Tags: banach-algebras, algebras

I am reading C*-algebras and Operator Theory by Gerard Murphy. It defines an algebra as a vector space $A$ together with a bilinear map
$$A^2\to A,\;\;\;(a,b)\mapsto ab,$$
such that
$$a(bc)=(ab)c\;\;\;(a,b,c\in A).$$
If a norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $A$ is submultiplicative, i.e. that
$$\|ab\|\leq\|a\|\|b\|\;\;\;(a,b\in A),$$ the pair $(A,\|\cdot\|)$ is called a normed algebra.

Murphy then uses the inequality $$\|ab-a'b'\|\leq\|a\|\|b-b'\|+\|a-a'\|\|b'\|$$ to prove that the multiplication $(a,b)\mapsto ab$ is jointly continuous. How does this inequality come about? Had there been a distributive law, one could have done like this:
$$\|ab-a'b'\|\leq\|ab-ab'\|+\|ab'-a'b'\|=\|a(b-b')\|+\|(a-a')b'\|\\\leq\|a\|\|b-b'\|+\|a-a'\|\|b'\|.$$
But, at least a priori, there isn't. So how should one attack this?

Comment: There is a distributive law, since we know that the multiplication map is bilinear.

Comment: Hint: What does the word "bilinear" mean?

Comment: @B.Mehta Oh, yes. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh, I see. Thank you.